# Cannot disable highlighting the first time UITableView selected?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have implemented `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` both in:

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { }
```

and in:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { }
```

But each row keeps geting blue selection first time it is clicked. How can I disable the selection entirely?

The code goes like this (The cell is custom):

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{    
    CategoryCell *cell = (CategoryCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;  
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //create cell
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

   return cell;

}
```

Comment: Thank you neighbor :), there is just 1 thing: I had to add selectionStyle property to my custom cell.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the ["`allowsSelection`" property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/allowsSelection) off for your table.

You can do this programatically or within the XIB / storyboard file.

Comment: I do not believe it is the answer. I do not want to disable the sell. I want to disable the highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

You should do it in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: This is the answer Omar gave me. It did help (after I have added selectionStyle propert to my custom cell). Thank you